# Maintenance: Assigning numbers to constants

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, constants

Consider the following constants I have in my app:

```
const Actions = {
    SONGS_CHANGED: 0,
    PREVIEW_TAG_CHANGES: 1,
    END_PREVIEW: 2,
    SAVE_TAGS: 3,

    PATTERNS_UPDATED: 4,
    PATTERN_MAPPED: 5,
    PATTERN_UNMAPPED: 6,

    CHANGE_NUMBER_OF_PARENT_DIRECTORIES: 7,
}
```

I'm trying to keep these grouped together. But that means if I add one to the first group, then I have to update the numbers for everything below it. Well, obviously I don't *have* to, I could always just assign it the next higher number (e.g. give the next constant a value of `8` regardless of which "group" I put it in). But as the quantity of constants increases, it will become harder to identify the highest number in order to know what the next one should be.

In python, using something like `range()` to just generate numbers for the constants removes this issue entirely. What's a good JavaScript approach?

Comment: `But as the quantity of constants increases` what does this mean?

Comment: @gurvinder372 Over time, as you add more constants to the application as requirements change.  OP would like to keep related constants grouped together but without the overhead of either renumbering or remembering/finding the current highest number

Comment: Do they need to be numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really do want to just number them in the order defined, you can use an incrementing variable to do so:

```
var x = 0;
const Actions = {
    SONGS_CHANGED: x++,
    PREVIEW_TAG_CHANGES: x++,
    END_PREVIEW: x++,
    SAVE_TAGS: x++,

    PATTERNS_UPDATED: x++,
    PATTERN_MAPPED: x++,
    PATTERN_UNMAPPED: x++,

    CHANGE_NUMBER_OF_PARENT_DIRECTORIES: x++,
}
console.log(Actions.END_PREVIEW); //2
console.log(Actions.SAVE_TAGS); //3
```

Note that changing constants in this fashion should only be used if the only place these numbers are used is by referencing the constants - if you're storing them elsewhere etc then changing them will break existing stored data.  The choice comes down to whether they're just constant at runtime, or should be permanently constant.

Answer (score 2):

If you know (or can estimate) a priori how big each group will ever be then you can use different subranges of numbers like this:

```
const Actions = {
    SONGS_CHANGED: 0,
    PREVIEW_TAG_CHANGES: 1,
    END_PREVIEW: 2,
    SAVE_TAGS: 3,

    PATTERNS_UPDATED: 10,
    PATTERN_MAPPED: 11,
    PATTERN_UNMAPPED: 12,

    CHANGE_NUMBER_OF_PARENT_DIRECTORIES: 50,
}
```

The advantage over James Thorpe's solution is that it is backwards compatible, i.e. you don't modify previously defined values ever.

Comment: Yep, another good approach.  My way should only really be used if the constants are the only place these numbers are used - if they've been stored elsewhere as just numbers, it will come back to bite you.  Added a note in that respect...

Comment: This is a great alternative solution, which would indeed be the way to go if I was concerned about the values never changing.

Answer (score 0):

A completely different approach that may or may not be suitable depending on what values your constants can take, but if they could be strings, for instance, you could use a GUID based approach:

```
const Actions = {
    SONGS_CHANGED:                       '4e6c355f-d684-4544-8320-529f20c89ce7',
    PREVIEW_TAG_CHANGES:                 '39a34b2b-0467-46f9-9d21-f407f89ae3c7',
    END_PREVIEW:                         '350e1d61-e6f9-4cc5-9364-bbdc14fd7063',
    SAVE_TAGS:                           '32e85a98-e13c-480c-9449-0a5bec7ec13c',

    PATTERNS_UPDATED:                    '16536175-e421-40d9-9d5d-962bcd0f0771',
    PATTERN_MAPPED:                      '0fd2bbd8-91f4-413b-8010-736bcacd1d88',
    PATTERN_UNMAPPED:                    'b946d566-d951-4695-a0ce-56b0bf987eb6',

    CHANGE_NUMBER_OF_PARENT_DIRECTORIES: '5b0736f5-e5e9-48f3-a9a1-bed8d0882beb',
}
```

You can then add new constants anywhere without worrying about changing existing values, or needing to know roughly how many you may need in the future.  There are plenty of ways of generating GUIDs, such as [this online tool](https://www.guidgenerator.com/online-guid-generator.aspx).